# How can I implement maxout layer for Linear layers with Torch7?

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

I already used TemporalMaxPooling layer but it does not work as I expected. I guess it gets input size nFeatures x nExamples where as Linear layers propagates nElements x nFeatures. This is of course my guess after I see size errors.

What is the right way to implement maxout in torch7? It is supposed to be easy but a hassle for a beginner.

Comment: Have you googled it? https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/4o2njp/how_to_implement_maxout_in_torch/